# How can I download a document using Laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel, download

I need to download a document from my DB, my file is on storage/app/manual

That's on my Controller

```
  protected function downloadFile($src)
{
    if(is_file($src))
    {
        $finfo=finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
        $content_type=finfo_file($finfo,$src);
       finfo_open($finfo);
       $file_name=basename($src).PHP_EOL;
       $size=filesize($src);
       header("Content-Type: $content_type");
       header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file_name");
       header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
       header("Content-Length: $size");
       
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
public function download(Request $request)
{
    $note=$request->file('manual')->store('/','manual');
    if(!$this->downloadFile(app_path(). $note))
    {
        return redirect("/machineIndex");
       
    }
}
```

On view

```
                <td><a name="Manual" href="{{url('user/download')}}">Manual</a></td>
```

Web

```
Route::get('/user/download','MachineController@download')->name('MachineController@download');
```

Laravel returns Error 404 not found or Call to a member function store() on null

Answer (score 0):

You have to return a download response in your controller :

```
return Response::download($yourFilePath, $yourFileName);
```

Also add a download name in your `<a name="Manual" href="{{url('user/download')}}" download="name.png">Manual</a>`

Comment: But I need to bring the file from DB, if I add a name it will return a wrong document. Not always is the same file.